# play sound on new message

Tags: android, ionic-framework, websocket

I am developing a system for a restaurant that makes it possible to order a dish online via website. The requirement is that a restaurant employee should install an android app that would play a sound in a loop when new order arrives.

The app works fine when it is an active state but it doesn't play the sound when in background (the app is made with Ionic, vue.js and capacitor).

I have tried:

- an [Insomnia plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/insomnia) that should stop the app from going to sleep (screen always visible is fine, the phone can be constantly charging; this doesn't work, after a while the app doesn't play audio when new order arrives)
- a [Background plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) that should run the app in the background mode (but the app is killed after a while anyways)

Not only the above didn't work but also are hackish solutions as far as I know.

What is a proper way to approach this? Ideally the app could be killed and the restaurant employee should still get the message. Any other ideas how to solve it (not necessarily with Ionic) are more that welcome.

[With the approaches above I am using websockets and a [audio plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio) to play the sound.]

Comment: For background or Killed State use Push notifications. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications. alternatively you can use Local Notifications to notify user.  https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications

Comment: When using push notification, would it be possible to open the app?

Comment: Yes, Clicking on Notification will open the Application.

Comment: thats the point, I don't want the user to click on the notification, I want it open instantly so that is starts playing audio in a loop instantly

Comment: No one can open application without user Interaction (specially in hybrid frameworks). If you Talking about something like Whatsapp call. you might have to make a plugin by yourself to achieve it.